# How do I use WordNet in Python?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

#### Code

```
wn.synset('accident.n.01').topic_domains()
```

#### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 1, in <module>
    wn.synset('accident.n.01').topic_domains()
AttributeError: 'Synset' object has no attribute 'topic_domains'
```

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: python 2.6.4 @PadraicCunningham

Comment: what version of nltk?

Comment: 2.0b8 @PadraicCunningham

Comment: You need to upgrade that is ancient

Comment: do u have a link that download a new version for python 2.6.4?

Comment: install it using pip